# Android Chromebook Layout Size

Tags: android, android-layout, chromebook

I'm trying to run my app on Chromebook. Currently the app loads fine in the in Chromebook. However Chromebook uses tablet layout `layout-sw720dp`. Is there a way I can differentiate between tablet and Chromebook layout? What if I make a `layout-sw1080dp`. Will that be specfic to Chromebook? At the end If I want to make a different layout for Chromebook what layout dimensions/size should I use? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you want to specifically target a Chromebook? If someone had a tablet with the exact same screen specs as a Chromebook, would you want it to have a different layout?

Comment: Yes that’s correct

Comment: Why? As far as your app is concerned, two identical screens are ... identical.

Comment: did you find out what would be the folder for chromebook? I also have to define few layouts for Chromebook but unable to find where to put them..

Comment: Sw1024 works the best in my opinion. I have tested it in few screen sizes.